# Throwing an error code: 9603 while creating a ADF linked service for Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, azure-data-factory

While creating a linked service with using Redshif it shows an connection failed with the below error:

```
Error Code: 9603 
ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][Amazon Redshift] (10) Error occurred while trying to connect: [SQLState 08S01] could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
    Is the server running on host "34.238.60.198" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

how to resolve this issue?

I would like to create a linked service with Redshift for loading data from ADF to Redshift.

Comment: What is the integration runtime you use, while creating linked service? Could you share the settings given while creating linked service?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received indicates that there is an issue with establishing a connection to your Amazon Redshift. The possible solutions provided in the AWS Redshift documentation suggest that the issue could be related to permission to access the cluster or with network traffic reaching the cluster because of firewall restrictions. .

To troubleshoot this issue, you can try the following steps:

Check the security group settings for your Amazon Redshift cluster. Make sure that the security group allows inbound traffic from the IP address or range that you are connecting from ADF. If you are using Azure IR you can download the IP range from here: [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) or if you your using SHIR, then whitelist SHIR public IP. You can add a new inbound rule to the security group to allow traffic from ADF integration Runtime.

Check the firewall settings for your Redshift network. If you have a firewall between your client and the Amazon Redshift cluster, make sure that the firewall allows inbound connections over the port that you are connecting to.
Ensure to allow inbound traffic from the IP addresses or range that you are connecting from ADF. If you are using Azure IR, you can download the IP range from here: [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) or if you your using SHIR, then whitelist SHIR public IP. You can add a new inbound rule to the security group to allow traffic from ADF integration Runtime.

If the above didn't work, try connecting to the Amazon Redshift from a different client tool or from a different network to see if the issue is specific to your current setup or specific to ADF.